# SELECT result set with fixed value decrements

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Using SQL Server 2008, I want to create a result set where a dynamic column decrements by fixed value.

Eg. consider I have a table of 600 rows and my dynamic column value should start at 360 and must end at 25 (distributed in select result set in decremented fashion) such that

```
(360-25) / 600 ~ 0.5583
```

So my decrement constant is 0.5583 now

```
id   col2   col3   dynamic_col4 
----------------------------------
1      abc    xyz    360          
2      lmn    dzx    359.44    
3      ojk    yk2    358.88    
4      pqr    pjr    358.32   
5      tml    dse    357.76      
.
.
.
.
558    uyh    pol    26.11 
559    oxy    pec    25.55   
600    djq    omn    25.00
```

See how the result set should start at 360 and in each row the value is decremented by 0.5583 until record 600 to reach 25.

Comment: `600 - (row_number * 0.5583)`, basically?

Comment: nope, how would that help 600 - (1 * 0.5583) = 599.4417 ?

Comment: sorry, `360 - etc...`, then... either way, it'd dynamically decrease your value as the row number increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `id` column is sequential, you can use it to calculate the dynamic column value. Or use `row_number` function to generate this sequential number and use it in the calculation.

```
select id,col2,col3,
360-((id-1)*0.5583) as dynamic_col4
from yourtable
where id>=1 and id<=600
```

To get the value to be decremented,

```
select id,col2,col3,
360-((id-1)*t.dec_val) as dynamic_col4
from yourtable y
cross join (select (max(col3)-min(col3))/1.0*count(*) as dec_val from yourtable) t
where id>=1 and id<=600
```

Comment: is it possible to get the 0.5583 value based on total records of result set in the query itself? say 360 and 25 would remain same but number of rows in result set might vary..

Comment: check if the edited version will suffice. where are the values 360 and 25 coming from? you should changed that probably.

Comment: its actually an ETA in seconds, however I do not need the actual ETA rather I prefer to create my own column based on number of rows in result

Comment: so finally its like 

`select row_number() over(order by id) as rowNum, col2, col3, (360-((row_number() over(order by id) -1) * t.dec_val)) as eta
from myTable y
cross join (select (360-25)/ (1.0 * count(*)) as dec_val from myTable) t`